# How 16.06.2016 is bigger than 29.10.2016

Tags: excel, vba, macros, compare

I have a macro to fill dates background if they are not forward than today. It works nicely but, however, just in one page, DateValues are not compared correctly.
I tried to show the result with MessageBoxes, it says 16.06.2016 is bigger than 29.10.2016

My macro:

```
Sub DolguRenkleri(ByVal StartIndex As Integer, ByVal EndIndex As Integer)
Dim Tarih As String
Dim Formul As String
Dim Formul2 As String
Tarih = Left(Now, 10)
For i = StartIndex To EndIndex - 1
MsgBox (Cells(i, 2).Value > DateValue(Tarih))
If Cells(i, 2) <= DateValue(Tarih) Then
With Range("A" + CStr(i), "H" + CStr(i))
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End With
Formul = "=TOPLA(D" + CStr(i + 1) + ":D" + CStr(EndIndex - 1) + ")"     
Formul2 = "=F6-A" + CStr(i)
Else: With Range("A" + CStr(i), "H" + CStr(i))
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End With
End If
Next i
 Range("F1").FormulaLocal = Formul
 Range("F7").FormulaLocal = Formul2
End Sub
```

Comment: Show your Excel too.

Comment: @FDavidov Here you are: http://www.mediafire.com/file/az937zmqfc54q4s/N%C4%B0%C4%9ESAC_GRUP_TAKS%C4%B0TL%C4%B0_KRED%C4%B0LER1.xlsm

Comment: @FDavidov Page is HALK 36 TKST 500 BİN 3

Comment: I prefer not to download things into my computer. A snapshot would do.

Comment: @FDavidov It's not that big though(200 kb) . Anyways: http://i.hizliresim.com/nEZBpM.png

Comment: Not because the size, but because the contents. In any case, I suggest that in the same messagebox that prints that `16.06.2016 is bigger than 29.10.2016`, add two lines with the types of the variables being compared. You get the typenames using the function `TypeName(<variable>)`.

Comment: @FDavidov It works perfectly on other pages, just it does not work with this page. Problem is not variables

Comment: Excel may show dates identically, but consider them as string and you would not notice till you try to use them for calculation. Please check the type as suggested above.

Comment: @FDavidow It returns false. But how these codes work with other pages then?

Comment: show a snapshot of a "working page" with active cell as the one where the date "works"

Comment: while in the "not working" page, while cell B10 is the active one, type in the immediate window `?ActiveCell.numberformat`, and press return to see the returned value

Comment: @user3598756 http://i.hizliresim.com/aXmmq5.png

Comment: @user3598756 I didnt understand what you said. Could you explain?

Comment: When you enter data into a cell, Excel assumes it represents certain type. For instance, if you enter "Abcd" in a cell it will be interpreted as text and aligned to the left, but if you enter 1234, it will be interpreted as a number and aligned to the right. Entering 10.9.2016 will be interpreted as a date BUT could be September the 10th or Octover the 9th, depending on your Locale settings. If your Locale is mm.dd.yyyy and you enter 15.9.2016, since there is no month "15", it will be interpreted as a string. That is why you should make sure that both fields are equally seen by Excel.

Comment: @FDavidov Oh,thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must be that "16.06.2016" string in cell B10 is not recognized as a real `Date` value, notwithstanding you may have selected that cell and assigned it a "Date" format

in this case, use

```
If DateValue(Replace(Cells(i, 2).Value, ".", "/")) <= DateValue(Tarih) Then
```

Comment: what is the value of the cell when it errors out like that?

Comment: 12.12.2016 and few more in that page

Comment: make one of that "wrong" cells the active one and then type in the immediate window (CTRL+G to show it in your IDE): `?Activecell.Text & " - " & ActiveCell.Value` and press return.

Comment: and what code line does throw that "type mismatch" error?

Comment: at the above line:If DateValue(Replace(Cells(i, 2).Value, ".", "/")) <= DateValue(Tarih) Then

Comment: Here is the output: 12.12.2016 - 12.12.2016

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126956/discussion-between-user3598756-and-talha-talip-acikgoz).